# Can I set a Firebase Realtime Database rule to read only when nodeId in request matches the nodeId in database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

My database structure

```
 {
        "messages": {
            "-top_level_random_push_id": { 
                "-child_level_random_push_id": { --- I don't have this id on device, I have all other id's defined here
                    "createdBy": "hgdhjstdvhhghjg6765HHH87AA", --- firebase uid
                    "message": "Hello",
                    "sentTo": "jhgsjdg6565KKKgsdsgdfGGGJ", ---- firebase uid
                    "timestamp": 1602047893089
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

// This is how I am reading from my android app

```
firebaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("messages").child("-top_level_random_push_id")
firebaseRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
}
```

Can I set a database rule to allow the read only if the request contains -top_level_random_push_id. Basically the read operation should be allowed only if conversions/-top_level_random_push_id === child node id from the client request

```
"conversations": {
            "$convoId": {
                ".indexOn": "timestamp",
                ".read": "$convoId == nodeId from the request" --- Not sure how to get this node id from request
            }
        },
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Your security rules only allow a user to read a conversation if they specify the `convoId` for that conversation. That matches nicely with the Android code you shared, so I'm not sure what is still missing here that you'd need in the `.read` rule.

Comment: Thanks Frank for checking. I guess I am overthinking the use case.

Comment: Oh, that wasn't what I meant to imply. I just think your rule may already do what you want if you set `".read": true` where you now have it. If that's not the case, I'd recommend posting the code that is not working against the rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the following rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "conversations": {
      "$convoId": {
        ".read": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then a user can only read a specific conversation of which they know the ID.

---

So your code to read the data:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("messages").child("-top_level_random_push_id")
```

Will be allowed because they specify an ID. If `-top_level_random_push_id` exists in the database, they'll get that data back. If it doesn't exist, they'll get an empty snapshot.

---

If you want to only allow the user to read the node if they specify the ID *and* it exists, you could do:

```
".read": "data.exists()"
```

The difference in this case is that the read will be rejected if the node doesn't exist, instead of them getting an empty snapshot.

---

If somebody tries to read all data with the following code:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("messages")
```

Then this read will be rejected by both rules above, because nobody has been given read permission to read the entire `messages` node in your rules.